# How to use stripe types in typescript

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create an application using loopback framework, which uses typescript. I want to use Stripe, and I installed both stripe and @types/stripe, because from what I understand, Typescript needs definite types.

I'm importing stripe as 
import * as stripe from 'stripe'

and I want to import the types as well so I'm doing 
import * as Stripe from '@types/stripe'

However, I'm getting the error:
 Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'stripe' instead of '@types/stripe'

How can I import the types so that I can use them to declare function returns, etc?

Comment: You don't explicitly import the declarations, just import the names from "stripe".

Comment: So do a separate import for the types? Like
import {ICustomer} from 'stripe'
or do stripe.ICustomer in the declaration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using `stripe-node` [1] directly, it now supports typescript and has types defined. For those who find this and are using the types from stripe-node, you can import Stripe like the following:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe(
  'sk_test_...', 
  {
    apiVersion: '2019-12-03',
    typescript: true,
  }
);
```

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#usage-with-typescript

Comment: Thanks so much! So I don't need to download the @types/stripe anymore?

Comment: Nope, these were recently shipped as part of the stripe-node library.

Answer (score 3):

You did correctly by installing stripe and @types/stripe. But, you don't need to import types declaration in the source file

```
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';

export const stripe = new Stripe('whateverkey');

function createHeader(): Stripe.HeaderOptions { // use stripe types for return type
  return 'stripe header';
}
```

if you use VSCode or IDE editor, it should give you IntelliSense such as below

[image]

Hope it helps